# GCC won't compile cleanly because of strcpy() and sizeof()

Tags: c, arrays

When I call `strncpy()` with an uninitialized string like this

```
strncpy(person->name, string, sizeof(person->name));
```

and then compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror`, and I see this error:

```
src/parser.c:18:35: error: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘strncpy’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]
   strncpy(person->name, string, sizeof(person->name));
```

I see that some other posts mentioned array decay in C, is it the same thing in this case? What would be the correct way to use `strncpy()` in this function then?

Edit: first, I `malloc'd` the struct as well as the string, and then I called `strncpy()`. Here is what the struct looks like:

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
  int age;
  int phone_num;
} person_t;
```

Comment: Ask yourself : "What is the value of `sizeof(person->name);`"?  It isn't what you think it is.  Once you see this, then ask "what function gives me the number of characters in the buffer?".

Comment: `sizeof(person->name)` == `sizeof (char *)`, not `sizeof(the number of bytes malloc-ed)`

Comment: Neither of the duplicates are relevant, this question has nothing to do with strlen. Clearly the poster thinks that sizeof will give the size of the allocated block.

Comment: Would `strncpy(person->name, string, strlen(string) + 1)` work then?